# Zend Framework ajaxLink params not being sent to ctr/action method

Tags: zend-framework

I have a simple ajaxLink to a controller. It works without the params, but when I add a param I get an error:

`Warning: Missing argument 1 for Ez_ContactsController::testyAction()`

The params are required and I see them in the jquery that ZF creates. here is the JS that gets generated (/ez is my module):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.ajaxLink1').click(function() { $.post('/ez/contacts/testy', {"param1":"1","param2":"456"}, function(data, textStatus) { $('#testy').html(data); }, 'html');return false; });
});
```

Here is my ajaxLink:

```
<div id="testy"></div>
<?= $this->ajaxLink("Example 2",
"/ez/contacts/testy",
array('update' => '#testy',
      'class' => 'someLink'),
array('param1' => '1',
      'param2' => '456')); ?>
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.
You don't send the vars directly to the function, they are sent via GET or POST.

Here is how I got the vars.
$param1 = (int)$this->_request->getParam('param1');
$param2 = (int)$this->_request->getParam('param2');

Here is the entire function:
public function testyAction(){

```
//The request was made with JS XmlHttpRequest
$this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(); //Will not render view
    $this->_helper->Layout->disableLayout(); // Will not load the layout
$param1 = (int)$this->_request->getParam('param1');
$param2 = (int)$this->_request->getParam('param2');

    echo 'testy 123. params sent were: '.$param1.', '.$param2;
```

}